# Set div width equal to window size

Tags: html, css, width

I have a container of width 1300 px. Inside the container i have other div.
I need to set the inner div width equal to browser window size eg) 1900px.
The content should be responsive to the window size.

My html code is like below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Some style goes here </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
   width: 1300px;
} 

.content{
  width: 100%
}`
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have the div width in `px` format it wont be responsive. 
It has to be in `%` format. If you put the inner content as `width:100%` The inner content will have a width of the '.container'.
So in order to get the inner div to be the window width you should have the `.container` to be equal to the window width.

CSS:

```css
.container{
   width:100%;
}
```

Or if you want we can use jQuery:

```js
 var w = $(window).width();
 $('.content').css('width', w);
```

Comment: if number of divs followed like horizontal scroll then use `min-width: 100%;` to take each div in full width. This is comment if for **HELPS SOMEONE**

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you want to open your `content` div as a modal window, hiding rest of the body elements. Try this [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eCuCoDE/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

change container to

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a fixed `width: 1300px;`, you can not have a `responsive to the window size` div

As codehorse said, add

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
}
```

but add

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

to you css as `width: 100%;` will render correctly if the dimension of the parent elements have been set beforehand!!

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4a3f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

remove default(bootstrap) max-width of container and set content width to 100%

```
.content{
      width: 100%;
}

.contianer{
       max-width: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of the .content (child div) equal (100%) to the browser window size instead of equal (100%) to the .container size (father div):

```
.container {
   width: 1300px;
} 

.content{
  width: 100vw;
}
```

1vw is 1% of the width of the viewport